# What causes 'Error while evaluating property extraGeneratedResDir' when running Flutter app with Firebase backend?

Tags: flutter, firebase

i use flutter 3.10.2.

After I added Firebase to my Flutter project. I encountered the following error to run the application:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`
```

how can i fix this error?

i use following command but not work:
`flutter clean`
`flutter pub get`